# Did Admiral Nechayev Order Picard to Commit Genocide?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg

In [Descent Part I](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Descent_(episode)), Admiral Nechayev arrives on the Enterprise and says the following to Picard (emphasis added):

> NECHAYEV: As I understand, it you found a single Borg at a crash site ...and eventually found a way to send it back to the Borg with a programme that would have destroyed **the entire collective once and for all**...
>   Now I want to make it clear that if you have a similar opportunity in the future, **an opportunity to destroy the Borg**, you are under orders to take advantage of it.

According to Memory Alpha, [genocide](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Genocide) is defined as:

> a deliberate, systematic destruction of an ethnic, racial, religious, or national group.

While the Borg are made up of thousands of species and therefore have no race, ethnicity or religion to speak of, it is easy to see that they are a nation unto themselves.

Given this, did Nechayev order that Picard should commit genocide?

Follow up: One of the tenets of the [Prime Directive](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Prime_Directive) is not:

> Taking actions to generally affect a society's overall development

If the Admiral DID order genocide, was it a legal order in light of the Prime Directive and considering that killing the entire species would obviously affect it's development?

Comment: 1. Obviously. The question is whether it was the right thing to do in light of the thousands of species that the Borg intend to destroy. 2. The Prime Directive does not apply to civilizations more technologically advanced than the Federation.

Comment: We know it applies to LESS advanced species and, on at least one occasion, Picard applied it to equally advanced species (in regard to the Klingon civil war) why not more advanced species?

Comment: According to Picard's moral compass, yes. That is exactly the reason he decided not to go through with it. I'm sure many more Federation citizens besides Nechayev would disagree with his choice.

Comment: See also [The Noncentral Fallacy](http://lesswrong.com/lw/e95/the_noncentral_fallacy_the_worst_argument_in_the/) on Less Wrong.  PS: Picard's dilemma was later retconned to some extent, in that *Voyager* makes it look much less likely that the attempt would have succeeded in eliminating the Borg.  It would probably have majorly pissed them off though. :-)

Comment: Yes but justifiably, in the same way that she might have ordered an armed policeman to shoot a terrorist with a machine gun, were she in that position, thus technically ordering him to commit murder. Genocide of the Borg would prevent them from committing many other genocides.

Comment: @Adamant - The Prime directive has two parts; 1) Not contacting civilisations that are pre-warp and 2) Not interfering with non-Federation species.

Comment: @colmde I disagree. Firing on a suspect in the commission of a crime is one thing. Hunting down and killing his entire terror cell, coworkers, family and friends is another thing altogether. A borg cube has a crew compliment of up to 130,000 drones. Only two cubes ever presented a real danger to the Federation. This means that literally trillions of borg would die for the actions of a tiny fraction of their race

Comment: But yet think of the genocide the bird commit on a weekly basis

Comment: Are the Borg a nation, species, or even a population? They exist as a collective separately embodied single consciousness... more like an (insanely intelligent) individual than a population. Upshot: perhaps the admiral ordered Picard to commit *murder*.

Comment: geewhiz - it doesn't matter if genocide violates the Prime Directive. The Prime Directive is not the only law, regulation, ethical principal, or rule that Starfleet members have to obey, nor is it the only law, regulation, ethical principal, or rule that that 21st century Humans can and must use to judge whether an an action is unethical and criminal.   As far as I know no military organization in our world has a rule like the Prime Directive, but some members of some military organizations have been accused of genocide anyway.

Comment: Since the Borg seem at least as advanced as any Federation species, how could the Prime Directive be relevant?

The Borg are an obvious and permanent threat to the Federation, its allies and even any grouping that might recognize the concept, "my enemy's enemy is my friend"… ie, everyone except the Borg.

Is that danger not "clear" to everyone? What does that leave to consider but whether that danger is also "present"?

To a clear and present existential threat, what choice could Starfleet have but kill or be killed… including "genocide".

Answer (score 6):

### Admiral Nechayev ordered a Genocide, but did not violate the Prime Directive.

As is [also noted in Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Prime_Directive#Inconsistencies_and_Exceptions%5C), the Prime Directive has various exceptions, including:

- Societies already in diplomatic negotiations with the Federation.
- Already contaminated cultures where the Federation could potentially "repair" the contamination.
- Distress calls targeted directly at Federation Vessels.
- **Societies that hail *or attack* a Federation vessel.**

---

**The Borg had already attacked Federation vessels, exempting them from the Prime Directive.**

---

**BUT:** Although this exemption might justify the order in the eyes of Starfleet command, it does not exempt the commanding officer (or Starfleet itself) from the ethical dilemma of Genocide. This debate is best illustrated in the [TNG episode "I, Borg" (S05E23)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/I_Borg_(episode)), where the crew debates the morality of using an individualized Borg as a delivery system for a virus (essentially a biological weapon for the Borg).